# Shell Script : Evaluate if condition through the expression in a variable

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I have a slightly complicated requirement to built up a expression based on values can be configured from a properties file.

I am able to build my expression as a string after reading the properties file but I am not able to get the expression evaluated with the IF condition

```
cat $var_inputFile | while read line
do
        arrIN=(${line//:/ })
        echo $matchPattern
        #if [[ ${arrIN[3]} = "SOA" && ${arrIN[2]} = "US" ]]
        if [[ $matchPattern ]]
        then
                echo $line
        fi
done
```

The `echo $matchpattern` prints

> ${arrIN[3]} = "SOA" && ${arrIN[2]} = "US"

If i uncomment the line the filtering works fine

```
    #if [[ ${arrIN[3]} = "SOA" && ${arrIN[2]} = "US" ]]
```

However the line below matching nothing

```
if [[ $matchPattern ]]
```

Is there a way to construct the expression into a variable and then use the variable to evaluate the if condition?

Comment: I managed to get it working by using eval

Comment: Note that in bash your variables will not be visible outside the loop because you are running it in a subshell.  The use of an unnecessary cat and pipe means both sides of the pipe run in their own child process.  You should redirect the filename into the final `done` instead `done < "$var_inputFile"` (and always quote your filename variables).

Comment: The variable `$matchPattern' is undefined in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use `eval` to execute a string.

Moreover, it is wise to use double quotes around variable references like `${arrIN[3]}` since otherwise you'll get a syntax error if the variable happens to be empty.

Then you can use

```
if eval "[[ $matchPattern ]]"
```